# Boost.Any get original type

Tags: c++, boost, types

I need to cast an `any` variable to an original type.
I need to do this:

```
int i = 10;
any a(i);
int& i2 = any_cast<int &>(a);
```

But I want that the type stores in `any` variable. And I write this:

```
int i = 10;
any a(i);
a::type_value& i2 = any_cast<a::type_value &>(a); // there is no actually type_value
```

How can I do something like that? Or how can I extract the original type from the `any` variable? Boost.variant is convenient either.

If I cannot do that, then I have another question what C++ techniques and libraries can store and get the type through a function to solve this issue?

Comment: You simply _can't_ do this with Boost.Any, so using Boost.Variant instead is going to be the basic answer.

Comment: *Why* do you need to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

C++ is a *statically* typed language. The type of a `boost::any` is a *runtime* value; any particular `any` could have any type. That's kinda the point.

There is no `any::type_value`, because that would have to be a *compile time* value. And `any` is a runtime construct.

Consider this:

```
void TakeAnAny(boost::any a)
{
  a::type_value& i2 = any_cast<a::type_value &>(a);
}
```

What type is `any::type_value`? It is legal to call `TakeAnAny` with virtually *any* type. There is no single compile-time type that `any::type_value` could reduce to. And therefore, there is no way for the compiler to determine a type. Since C++ is statically typed, you're hosed.

The ultimate purpose of any is type-erasure. I have some value. And I want to pass that to some other function. This process will go through several different communication layers. But I don't necessarily want all of those different layers to know exactly what type I'm using. I only need myself and my intended destination to know the type. So you stick it in an `any` and you're fine. Everyone else just sees the `any`, and both of you know what it wraps.

This process only works because both the source and the destination know the real type of the value. If you don't know the type, then you shouldn't be using `any`. The purpose of `any` is not have a function sit there and cast it to a bunch of possible types (that's what `boost::variant` is for). The purpose is to erase the type from a function's signature.

This allows for things like generic messages and signals. You register some event handler with a system. You fire an event that takes an `any` as a parameter. The person firing the event knows that the "MouseClick" event always takes a `vec2` as its parameter. So every "MouseClick" handler casts it to a `vec2`. The "KeyPress" event would maybe pass a `int32_t`. So those handlers cast it to that type. And so forth. Everyone knows what type it actually takes.

This used to be done with `void*`. The problem there is that you have ownership issues (`any` is a value, while `void*` is a pointer). Also, a `void*` is so type-erased that there's no way to check to see if your cast is correct. `any` is really just a type&value-safe `void*`; it prevents you from casting to the *wrong* type.

You don't really want `any`. Your use case doesn't seem to want `variant` either. What you seem to want is a *template*. That's a different kind of thing, and it would let you do what you really want: have a function that can use any particular type, while still being able to know exactly what that type is.

Of course, templates have their own limitations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a map of `std::type_info` to `std::function<void(boost::any const&)>` object to deal with the types you are aware of and you want to deal with: you would locate the entry in the map using `a.type()` and call the corresponding function which would know how to deal with the argument.

Comment: If one is aware of the types they're going to be dealing with, then why would one use Boost.Any instead of Boost.Variant in the first place?

Comment: It seems a simpler type to pass along. Also, there may be interfaces which take `boost::any` as arguments and eventually call a function where the `boost::any` is given back in some form. For example, it seems that attaching a `boost::any` to an object to hold arbitrary information is a reasonable thing and the user of the class may very well know which types he might attach.

Comment: Given _that specific scenario_ then I agree that `boost::any<>` may be appropriate; after all, the library does exist for a reason. But somehow I doubt the OP is in that specific scenario, and I would still vote for Boost.Variant unless the OP has a specific reason that's not feasible. ;-]